# Would giving up on 'ex falso' change anything w.r.t. dependently-typed programming in Coq?

Tags: coq, dependent-type

Coq seems to assume ex falso quodlibet / the principle of explosion (PEP).

The induction principle generated from a data type definition with no constructors *is* PEP:

```
False_ind = 
fun (P : Prop) (f : False) => match f return P with
                              end
     : forall P : Prop, False -> P
```

This principal seems to be necessary for proving things like disjunctive syllogism:

```
Lemma disj_syll : forall (A B: Prop), A \/ B -> (not B) -> A.
Proof.
intros.
destruct H.
- (* prove A from A *) assumption.
- (* prove A from B and ~B *) contradiction.
Qed.
```

So that's what PEP buys us in terms of *proving*. But what about ***programming***?

I can't figure out what it would mean to drop PEP and am really confused by the program extraction output.

As far as I can tell:

- the extractions are the same for *all* proofs that rely on PEP, including the one above
- the extractions for Scheme and Haskell seem to do *completely different things*

Scheme:

```lisp
(load "macros_extr.scm")
(define __ (lambda (_) __))
(define disj_syll __)
```

Haskell:

```hs
module Disj_syll where
import qualified Prelude

__ :: any
__ = Prelude.error "Logical or arity value used"

disj_syll :: ()
disj_syll =  __
```

What is going on?

I'm asking this question because the connection between proofs and programs (Propositions-as-Types / Curry-Howard Isomorphism) seems well-understood for the logical connectives generally, but PEP is an **axiom** in Heyting and Kolmogorov's formalizations of intuitionistic logic ([Kolmogorov and Brouwer on constructive implication and
the Ex Falso rule, Van Dalen 2004](http://aleteya.cs.buap.mx/%7Ejlavalle/papers/van%20Dalen/Kolmogorov%20and%20Brouwer%20on%20constructive%20implication%20and%20the%20Ex%20Falso%20rule.pdf)). It's hard for me to see what the computational content of such an axiom is, especially when it says "Given that you have constructed the unconstructable, you now get (for free!) a construction of anything you choose to imagine)." I don't know how to write a program to do such a thing, and Coq's program extraction doesn't seem to have a consistent perspective on the matter either.

Comment: Your question regarding extraction is ill-posed. Coq's extraction assumes a non-informative `Prop`, so any type that lives in `Prop` gets extracted to something akin to the unit type. In particular, your lemma `disj_syll` gets extracted to the unit value. (Because of cumulativity, this value looks like a recursive function in Scheme and OCaml, but it is still meant to be understood as a singleton.) As a consequence, you are not exercising the extraction of PEP, you are just seeing how Coq's extraction encodes non-informative types.

Comment: Thanks!! That was a silly mistake. Now I'm trying to re-do the example in `Set` using parallel definitions of `or` and `False` and (after 5 minutes) I haven't been able to prove disjuntive syllogism.

Comment: The proof should be exactly the same as in the `Prop` case: `Lemma disj_syll A B : or' A B -> (B -> false') -> A. Proof. intros [J|J] K. easy. contradiction. Defined.`

Answer (score 3):

The standard computational interpretation for PEP is just the program *crashing*, since it requires a logically impossible premise. In the Scheme code, crashing is represented by the program looping, and in Haskell, this is a toplevel exception. But in both cases we know this is dead code and should never be reached, except if Coq is inconsistent itself.

Note that Coq is consistent with alternative computational interpretations of PEP, though. One can apply a variant of Friedman's *A*-translation to Coq to replace crashing by raising *recoverable* exceptions. See the [Exceptional model](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01840643/document) for more details.

Comment: What would be the consequences of giving up PEP in Coq?

Comment: Probably not much, since you can encode propositional falsity as the impredicative encoding `forall A : Prop, A`. There is probably even a way to get around singleton elimination by considering fancier dependent eliminations. So, in the end you'd get a fairly ad-hoc system, with asymmetrical, arbitrarily restricted elimination on zero-constructor inductive types.

Comment: As a matter of fact, here is a variant of PEP that doesn't rely on elimination of an empty inductive type, using indices instead.

    Definition another_PEP : forall A, true = false -> A := fun A e =>
      match e in _ = b
        return match b with true => unit | false => A end
      with
      | eq_refl => tt
      end.

Comment: re the variant PEP: I proved something of the same type with `intros. inversion H` and got this extraction for Scheme: `(define foo (lambda (_) (error "absurd case")))`. So sometimes Coq decides to error in the Scheme output, and sometimes to do a silly infinite loop.

Comment: What I want to know is why we have to do anything at all in the absurd cases and why Coq needs to generate code for them. In most programming languages, you don't have to do anything in the unreachable parts, and in some you can even get the compiler to verify the code is unreachable. PEP seems silly to me: instead of saying that all wishes are granted to those who have already done the impossible, we could just not talk about such situations, right?

Comment: @MaxHeiber It's not always trivial to detect when a case is impossible. E.g. if I have `(a b c n : positive), (prf : a^n + b^n = c^n)`, then the only possible cases are `n = 1` and `n = 2`. There's no hope of Coq just *guessing* the proof of Fermat's last theorem when I don't write the cases for `n >= 3`. Therefore, (the core of) Coq doesn't try to detect these situations. It's your job to find them (by proving `False` and using PEP). Plugins like Equations can sometimes automate this, achieving the "we could just not talk about such situations". But we *must* talk about them in general.

Comment: @MaxHeiber Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "most programming languages, you don't have to do anything in the unreachable parts." Those programming languages impose some undesirable default in the unreachable cases, *and* they generally warn you that you *should* be doing something in those unreachable cases. A program written in Coq is supposed to *never crash*, so it doesn't "error by default". You can't just say "every case I ignore is impossible" because there's just no reason for that to be true. You have to justify the claim each time (and, as I say, sometimes that can be automated).

Comment: Justifying the claim that a case is unreachable sounds reasonable. It seems a step further to get a free proof for anything we want once we have shown that a case is unreachable. I haven't been able to come up with a case where this distinction amounts to anything, except in the generated code.

Comment: Note that the exceptional model precisely allows not to have to write anything in branches known to be dead by the intercession of Santa Klaus, since you can just raise an exception. Obviously, the price to pay is that the resulting theory is inconsistent, just as the logic arising from those languages that allow to skip branches. In general you can't get "hassle-free dead code", consistency and decidability of type-checking at the same time.

Comment: @MaxHeiber The unreachable case can have any expected type, so whatever kind of expression is used to say "this case is unreachable" must be able to have any type. And it has to be an expression, not some kind of extension to `match`, since we want to package `match`s without losing anything (e.g. `sum_rect` is a "packaged `match`", and `(sum_rect (fun _ => _) (Empty_set_rect _) (fun x => x))` shows an "unreachable case" without any visible "case-ing"). There are probably many ways you can think to do it, but a simple(st), natural (and therefore conventional) way is induction on empty types.

Comment: Here's some intuition about *It seems a step further to get a free proof for anything we want once we have shown that a case is unreachable.*: showing that a case is unreachable is done by proving that being in that case implies `False`.  `False` is an empty type, so if you can construct something in *that* type, surely it can't be harder to "get a free proof for anything we want".

Answer (score 3):

> Would giving up on 'ex falso' change anything w.r.t. dependently-typed programming in Coq?

Yes, it would. Let us consider the hello-world of dependently typed programming, namely length-indexed lists (a.k.a. vectors). It is defined in the standard library, but let me give it here for context.

```
Inductive vec (A : Type) : nat -> Type :=
  | vnil : vec A 0
  | vcons n : A -> vec A n -> vec A (S n).
```

Now, we might want to provide the analogue of the `head` function on regular (non-indexed) lists. There is many approaches to deal with the case of the empty list as the input of `head` for lists. But for vectors it is especially easy to ask for non-empty input: we put this restriction in the type of the input `v : vec A (S n)`, where `S n` ensures that the length of the input vector is not zero.

Here is a stub for this function:

```
Fixpoint head {A n} (v : vec A (S n)) : A :=
  match v with
  | vnil _ => _
  | vcons _ n hd tl => hd
  end.
```

But what do we return in case of the empty input? Coq won't let us simply omit `vnil` constructor in the pattern-matching expression. Here we can use the principle of explosion to solve the issue. Here is one possible way to fill in the blank above:

```
Fixpoint head {A n} (v : vec A (S n)) : A :=
  match v in vec _ len
        return (len = S n -> A)
  with
  | vnil _ => fun contra => False_rect _ (O_S _ contra)
  | vcons _ n hd tl => fun _ => hd
  end eq_refl.
```

This solution uses the so-called "convoy pattern" which is described in several Stackoverflow answers and in the CPDT book by Adam Chlipala. It also uses the standard `O_S` lemma (of type `forall n : nat, 0 <> S n`), so `(O_S _ contra)` has type type `False`.

Comment: This answer essentially repeats the statement "But in both cases we know this is dead code and should never be reached" from a great answer by perthmad.

Comment: Re "Coq won't let us simply omit vnil constructor in the pattern-matching expression" - why not? Essentially the same question as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63315830/would-giving-up-on-ex-falso-change-anything-w-r-t-dependently-typed-programmi/63316257#comment111964289_63316257

Comment: @MaxHeiber For the same reason that it doesn't let us omit the vcons constructor: it has no way of knowing which cases are possible and which are not (it's undecidable).